# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds and quit

Tags: php, ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, system

I am getting unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7056) and quit error When I am trying to run php script which gives command to system to run a ruby script for automation. Ruby script uses selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but do you set max time limit for your script ?

```
set_time_limit(60); //60 seconds
```

Comment: In ruby, Timeout has been set for 180 secs for selenium client

Comment: `Watir.default_timeout = 180`  
`$client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new`  
`$client.timeout = 180 # seconds – default is 60`

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

update selenium-webdriver gem on your machine by running this command.

```
gem update selenium-webdriver
```

Comment: I have tried that also, It says nothing to update. Current version for gem is 2.53.0